# Visual Studio 2010 .suo file w.r.t. linking

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran, static-linking

I am having a considerable amount of trouble statically linking one of my Fortran projects - while the existing ones in the solution work fine.  While trying to work out why, I've been combing the various options in VS2012's project and solution properties, and cannot find any differences.  I have then moved on to searching the metadata of the solution and projects using Notepad++'s 'find in files' function.

The only difference I've found in the metadata so far is that the search term "*working library*.lib" appears in the binary file .suo a number of times, whereas the search term "*not linking library*.lib" does not appear in the .suo at all.  Their respective projects both appear in the .sln file in an apparently identical manner.

Could anyone tell me whether:

1)  The .suo file is binary, and the search is not working and returning false positives.

2)  The .suo does in fact fail to mention "*not linking library*.lib", which is why I have a problem.

As the .suo file is derived data and not under source control, *something* must be specifying what goes into it - but what.  The MSDN website only says what API's are available to extract data...

Comment: I have always assumed everything of interest was contained in the source files and vfproj file. As far as I know the suo file is purely things like which windows are currently open.

Comment: That's what I had thought - it certainly *ought* to be the case.  If it *does* only contain metadata, then Notepad++ must be mistaken about finding a reference to the .lib file - I don't know whether text searches in a binary file have any validity at all.

Comment: It may not be a simple matter the project properties being consistent across your solution, the troublesome project may actually require some special linker option. Can you give any more detail on what the "trouble" is?